# Оптимизация программы вычисления суммы НОД

Tags: java, алгоритм, теория-чисел

В задаче нужно нужно найти **G** по введенному значению **n**. **GCD(i,j)** - НОД чисел **i** и **j**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа работает так, как нужно, но для больших **n** время выполнения колоссально (при **n**=30000, например, программа выполняется около минуты).

Можете подсказать, каким образом её можно оптимизировать?

Некоторые вопросы:

1) Судя по суммам, числа **i** и **j** - числа Фибоначчи, прав ли я? И если да, может ли это каким-то образом помочь облегчить алгоритм поиска НОД (Наибольший общий делитель двух чисел Фибоначчи равен числу Фибоначчи с индексом, равным наибольшему общему делителю индексов)? Для поиска НОД я использовал алгоритм Евклида.

2) Можно ли каким-то образом ускорить вычисление суммы, то есть избежать использования двух вложенных циклов и огромного количества итераций, вытекающих из них?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner reader  = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
       for( ; ; ) {
         n = reader.nextInt();
     if(n>1 && n<4000001) a.add(n);
     else if(n==0) break;
     }

 int  i, j;

for (int k=0; k<a.size(); k++) {
    n=a.get(k);
    long G = 0;
    for( i = 1; i < n; i++) {
for( j = i + 1;j <= n; j++)
{
G += GCD(i,j);
}  
}

System.out.println(G);
}
    }
    static int GCD (int i, int j) {
      while (j !=0) {
            int tmp = i%j;
            i = j;
            j = tmp;
        }
        return i;     
    }

}
```

Comment: а насколько вам надо ускроить? если по мелочи то предпросчитать gcd() для всех пар (это уберёт log из сложности), заметить что gcd(i,j+i) = gcd(i,j) и использовать чтобы вложенный цикл был не полностью, но сложность будет порядка N^2 всё равно. Или глобально улучшить до N log N , но и решение будет сложнее. Или можете вообще просчитать у себя локально все ответы до 100'000 например и решение будет тупо вывод числа.

Comment: Судя по тому, что в примере случай для n=200000 выполнение занимает меньше десяти секунд, ускорить нужно очень сильно

Comment: Это вопрос не по программированию, а по математике. Узнайте у математиков, как свернуть ваше выражение во что-то покороче.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень крутой вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пишу общую идею.
Заметим что `GCD(i,j+i) = GCD(i,j)`. Таким образом мы можем выполнять `2 цикл от 0 до i` а получившийся результат умножать на количество вхождений (`N/i - (N%i < j)` ). Это снизит сложность до N^2/2, что всё равно много.

Теперь ещё 1 оптимизация. Будем пускать 2 цикл не по j а по результату.
Для этого сделаем факторизацию чисел от `1` до `N`, например модификация решета Эратосфена, главное не в "лоб" а за N или N log N.

`i` фиксировано.
Генерируем на основе факторизации все делители и отсортируем в порядке возрастания.

Цикл по делителям (`q`).
Количество вхождений `q` от `1` до `N` будет равно `N/q - i/q` (минус из-за того что цикл от `i+1` а не 1). Именно это значение (`N/q*q`) мы прибавляем к ответу. НО если `q` не простое то мы его учитывали при вычислении ответа для его делителя. Теперь мы должно вычесть это значение. Для каждого простого делителя `q` (`z`) (лучше тоже предпросчитать отдельно, меньше путаницы будет) мы должны вычесть `N/q*(q/z)` (1 раз для каждого `z`). Но некоторые мы вычтем так 2 раза (для 2 различных `z`).   Дальше используется лемма включения - исключения.

Рассмотрим на примере вычисления суммы когда `for (int i=1;i<=24;i++) ans+=GCD(24,i)` Такой пример для упрощения понимания.
Факторизация `24 =2*2*2*3` 
Делители `1 2 3 4 6 8 12 24`.
Суммы ответа пошагово:

```
24*1   = 24   -         0      +24
24/2*2 = 24;  - 12*1 = 12;     +12
24/3*3 = 24;  - 8*1  =  8;     +16
24/4*4 = 24;  - 6*2  = 12;     +12 
24/6*6 = 24;  - 4*(2+3-1)=16   +8
24/8*8 = 24;  - 3*4 = 12       +12
       = 24;  - 2*(6+4-2)=16   +8
       = 24;  - 1*(12+8-4)     +8
```

Итого                            +100.

Можете пересчитать что ответ правильный.

Сложность будет оценить тяжело, но будет что-то порядка N * sqrt(N).

P.S. в реальной задачи (не олимпиадной), я бы не делал всё это, а просчитал бы массив констант до сколько нужно (400'000 насколько я помню) и положил в отдельный файл, да он весил бы мегабайта 2-3, да он создавался бы полчаса, но зато все понимали как он генерируется и вероятность ошибки была бы низкая.

Comment: "GCD(i,j+i) = GCD(i,j)" -- неверно. GCD(2, 4) = 2 != 1 = GCD(2, 3)

Comment: @dzhioev простите, а 4 = 3 + 2?

Comment: извиняюсь, прочитал "j + 1" всесто "j + i"

Answer (score 2):

Вопросу скоро восемь лет, но функция интересная, так что попробуем её вычислить быстро.

## Короткий путь

По определению вычислим первые десять значений функции: *0, 1, 3, 7, 11, 20, 26, 38, 50*. Отыщем их в [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences® (OEIS®)](https://oeis.org). [Поиск](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+1%2C+3%2C+7%2C+11%2C+20%2C+26%2C+38%2C+50&go=Search) выдаст единственную последовательность: [A178881](https://oeis.org/A178881). А там в секции FORMULA определение, которое точно совпадает с формулировкой вопроса: `a(n) = Sum_{i=1..n-1, j=i+1..n} gcd(i,j)`. Это она. Есть даже ссылка на олимпиадную задачу, в которой надо вычислить эту функцию: Uva Online Judge Algorithm [Problem number 11424](https://onlinejudge.org/external/114/p11424.pdf). Формулировки той задачи и задачи в вопросе замечательно совпадают, кроме некоторых мелочей.

В секции LINKS есть ссылка на программу Akshay Bansal: [C program](https://oeis.org/A178881/a178881.c.txt). Программа вычисляет миллион значений функции *G*. Переводим на Java, добавляем ввод и вывод:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp {
    private static int[] makePhi(final int n) {
        int[] phi = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            phi[i] = i;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
            if (phi[i] == i) { // is prime?
                for (int j = i; j < n; j += i) {
                    phi[j] -= phi[j] / i;
                }
            }
        }
        return phi;
    }

    private static long[] makeG(int[] phi) {
        final int n = phi.length;

        long[] g = new long[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            g[i] = -i;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j += i) {
                g[j] += i * phi[j / i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            g[i] += g[i - 1];
        }
        return g;
    }

        
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            int n = s.nextInt();
            if (n == 0) {
                break;
            }
            a.add(n);
        }

        int[] phi = makePhi(Collections.max(a) + 1);
        long[] g = makeG(phi);

        for (int i : a) {
            System.out.println(g[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Время работы программы определяется максимальным числом во вводе. Для четырёх миллионов (подсмотрено в коде из вопроса) можно уложится в одну секунду:

> ```
> $ javac Temp.java 
>
> $ time echo 10 100 20000 4000000 0 | java Temp
> 67
> 13015
> 1153104356
> 71887733425828
>
> real  0m0.885s
> user  0m0.888s
> sys   0m0.024s
> ```

Если *n* - максимальное число в запросе, то программа отработает за *O(nlogn)* и потребует *O(n)* памяти.

## Почему она работает и работает так быстро

### Вычисление G - теория

*G(n) = ∑<sub>i=1..n-1</sub> ∑<sub>j=i+1..n</sub> НОД(i, j)*

Рассмотрим *G(n) - G(n - 1)*:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| *G(n) - G(n - 1) =* |  |
| *= ∑<sub>i=1..n-1</sub> ∑<sub>j=i+1..n</sub> НОД(i, j) - ∑<sub>i=1..n-2</sub> ∑<sub>j=i+1..n-1</sub> НОД(i, j) =* |  |
| *= ∑<sub>i=1..n-1</sub> ∑<sub>j=i+1..n</sub> НОД(i, j) - ∑<sub>i=1..n-1</sub> ∑<sub>j=i+1..n-1</sub> НОД(i, j) =* | Во второй сумме верхний предел можно увеличить на единицу. Новое слагаемое нулевое. |
| *= ∑<sub>i=1..n-1</sub> (∑<sub>j=i+1..n</sub> НОД(i, j) - ∑<sub>j=i+1..n-1</sub> НОД(i, j)) =* | Собираем суммы вместе. |
| *= ∑<sub>i=1..n-1</sub> НОД(i, n) =* | Сокращаем. |
| *= [∑<sub>i=1..n</sub> НОД(i, n)] - НОД(n, n) =* | Увеличиваем диапазон. |
| *= [∑<sub>i=1..n</sub> НОД(i, n)] - n* | *НОД(n, n) = n*. |

Займёмся функцией *h(n) = ∑<sub>i=1..n</sub> НОД(i, n)*. Это сумма *НОД* и она появляется в нескольких задачах. *НОД(i, n)* при фиксированном *n* и меняющемся *i* может принимать значения равные любому делителю *n*. Пусть *d* такой делитель, то есть *d|n*. *НОД(i, n) = d* тогда и только тогда, когда *d|i* и *НОД(i/d, n/d) = 1*.

Функция Эйлера считает сколько чисел меньше *n* и взаимно просты с ним: *φ(n) = ∑<sub>i=1..n,НОД(i,n)=1</sub> 1*.

Через функцию Эйлера можно выразить количество *i* при которых *НОД(i, n) = d*. Это *φ(n/d)*. Если сложить все такие *НОД(i, n)*, получится *d·φ(n/d)*. Тогда:

*h(n) = ∑<sub>d|n</sub> d·φ(n/d)*

В этой сумме *d* пробегает все делители *n*, для каждого делителя вычисляется количество *i* для которых *НОД(i, n)=d* и умножается на *d*.

Задача переформулируется так: вычислить *h(n)* для всех *n* из диапазона, скорректировать значения - вычесть из каждого *n*. Построить массив накопительных сумм. Этот массив содержит значения функции *G*.

### Вычисление G - практика

Будем считать что *φ(n)* уже вычислена.

Инициализация `g[i] = -i` отвечает за коррекцию значений. Два вложенных цикла накапливают слагаемые вида *i·φ(j/i)*, но делают это не для одного *n* а сразу для всех *j* кратных *i*.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            g[i] = -i;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j += i) {
                g[j] += i * phi[j / i];
            }
        }
```

Оценим время работы: *n + ∑<sub>i=2..n</sub>n/i*. Первое слагаемое - время работы заголовка внешнего цикла. Второе слагаемое - количество итераций внутреннего цикла. Сумма оценивается как *n∑<sub>i=1..n</sub>1/i = nH<sub>n</sub> < n(ln n + 1)* (см. [гармонический ряд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4)). Вся сумма есть *O(n·log n)*.

За *n·log n* можно вычислить *G* для диапазона, если известна *φ* для того же диапазона.

### *φ* - функция Эйлера

`makePhi` вычисляет [функцию Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). *φ(n)* - количество натуральных чисел не превосходящих *n* (*k ≤ n*) и взаимнопростых с *n* (*НОД(k, n) = 1*).

*φ(n) = n∏<sub>p|n</sub>(1 - 1/p)*, где *p* пробегает все простые числа на которые делится *n*. Следовательно для каждого конкретного *n* её можно вычислить по разложению *n* на простые множители. Разложение находится за *√n*. В нашей задаче требуется вычислить *φ* для диапазона чисел и вместе это можно сделать быстрее, чем для каждого значения в отдельности.

```
        for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
            if (phi[i] == i) { // is prime?
                for (int j = i; j < n; j += i) {
                    phi[j] -= phi[j] / i;
                }
            }
        }
```

Массив `phi` первоначально заполнен последовательными целыми числами: `phi[i] = i`. Оператор `if` отвечает за проверку простоты числа *i*. Если *i* простое, то все числа кратные *i* умножаются на *1 - 1/i*. Когда внешний цикл закончится, число с индексом *k* в массиве `phi` умножено на сомножители *1 - 1/p* для всеx простых *p* которые делят *k*. Что даёт произведение *k∏<sub>p|k</sub>(1 - 1/p)*, что равно *φ(k)*.

`if` срабатывает только для простых *k*, потому что если *k* составное, то оно делится на какое-то простое *i*, которое уже обрабатывалось раньше и во время этой обработки значение в массиве `phi[k]` стало меньше `k`.

Оценим время работы сверху. Для грубой оценки предположим что `if` всегда срабатывает. Тогда время работы будет таким же как для функции *G*: *O(n·log n)*.

Если принять во внимание что `if` срабатывает не каждый раз, то сложность оценивается как *O(n·log(log(n)))*. Это сложный анализ, я его опускаю.

Логарифм логарифма растёт так медленно что для всех практически доступных *n* (*n* - размер массива, который должен поместится в оперативной памяти) его можно считать константой. За линейное время можно построить *φ* для всех чисел в промежутке *[1, n]*.

Замечу что *φ* считается на промежутке так быстро потому что она [мультипликативная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), то есть может быть вычислена по разложению аргумента на простые множители. Мультипликативных функций много и все они вычисляются на интервалах за почти линейное время.